# How do i structure a serverless application using Azure Durable Functions?

Tags: azure

I am trying to work out the best practice for structuring a series of Azure durable functions for reuse across future development work within my organisation.

From the doc's it seems like the desired approach is to setup single use activity functions, and then reuse them within different orchestrations, but what is the best practice and how do i achieve this in visual studio?

For example can i simply create a class library with all of my activity functions in it and share it between different vs projects for each orchestration?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer seems to be that, rather than keeping a class library of Activity/orchestration functions. I can just share a Class Library of Functions with my various Apps and simply call the relevant function from the activity function. This way if I need to reuse functionality I can do so without introducing every activity function to every function app.